# Will files from SDK i edited be re written after pod install?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using an open source pod, and once in XCode I made some changes in the code to some of the features my question is will these changes be overridden when I run 'pod install' again ? or when a new version of the pod comes out ? how does this work since we made changes to some of the code ?

Comment: Yes they will. If you need permanent changes then you should fork the code and use a private version of the pod (you can specific your own repo in the podfile). If the changes would be generally useful consider submitting a pull request back to the project.

Comment: okay thanks alot for the information ! if i was to fork it and use a private version what happens when a new version of the pod comes out ? Is the only way possible to use it is by forking that version ?

Comment: Once you fork then it is your responsibility to merge in any updates from the upstream, if you want them.  Otherwise you can just continue to use your fork as-is.  Generally you should see if you can get the behaviour you need by subclassing or using an extension rather than modifying the original framework.